# Which one is better ? Omniauth or Omniauth+Devise for twitter verification?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If i use omniauth for twitter verification.. code for the following is

```
def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Successfully signed in"
end
```

but if i use omniauth+devise for twitter verificaiton.. code for the following is

```
def twitter
    omni= request.env["omniauth.auth"]
authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omni['provider'],omni['uid'])
if authentication
    flash[:notice]="Logged in successfully"
    sign_in_and_redirect User.find(authentication.user_id)
elsif current_user
    token=omni['credentials'].token
    token_secret=omni['credentials'].secret
    current_user.authentications.create! (:provider=>omni['provider'],:uid=>omni['uid'],:token=>token,:token_secret=>token_secret)
    flash[:notice]="Authentication successful."
    sign_in_and_redirect current_user
else
    user=User.new
    user.apply_omniauth(omni)
        if user.save
        flash[:notice]="Logged in."
        sign_in_and_redirect User.find(user.id)
    else
        session[:omniauth]=omni.except('extra')
        redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end 
end
end
```

Which one is better Omniauth or Omniauth+Devise?

Answer (score 2):

`Devise` will give you certain ready made helper functions like `current_user`, `user_signed_in?` and controller filters like `before :authenticate_user!`.

Though they are very basic to implement on our own, but when `omniauth-twitter` alone, you will have to implement on your own.

If you don't plan to have very sophisticated user authentication and just want simple twitter based authentication, you can go ahead and use `omniauth-twitter` alone. Devise will open your application for mannual (form based) registrations by default, which you may not want.

Comment: Thanks @kiddorails for detailed answer. Basically i am developing a social network. I will be using my own sign up form as well as authentication for Twitter, Facebook and google. i am looking for something which will be faster.which one would be better .omniauth or omniauth+Twitter?(which one would you used.

Comment: @user1990200 Nice. Okay, I have these two applications; in one I offered Facebook, twitter and mannual sign-up; and for that I used Devise with `omniauthable` strategy. In other application, I only needed Facebook login mechanism, so I went ahead and just used omniauth-facebook. 
For your case, I will advice you to use Devise + Omniauth. Details about implementation - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview